# Logging with Python, ROS, and C++

Tags: python, c++, logging, ros

I have a codebase of Python and C++ code, including heavy use of ROS. Logging is done throughout the Python code with both [system logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) and [rospy logging](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging) -- contrived example:

```
import logging
import rospy

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def run():
    rospy.loginfo("This is a ROS log message")
    LOG.info("And now from Python")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runt()
```

As for C++ code we need to add logging, probably with [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) but I'm open to other options.

**Is there a way to integrate the various loggers into one module?** Ideally a user could do something like `my_logger = AwesomeLogger(level='info', output='my_logs.txt')` and then `AwesomeLogger` behind the scenes sets up the Python and C++ loggers, and combines all log outputs (including from ROS) into clean console messages output text file.

Note we target support for ubuntu 16.04, ROS-kinetic, C++11, Python 2.7*

*If a solution provides rational for moving to Python 3.6 you get bonus points!

**UPDATE**
If I load a dict config from yaml (as described in [this post on logging best practices](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/) I can specify handlers and loggers for ROS. But with the yaml below I get duplicated rospy log messages to the console, one in the standard rospy log format and the other in my specified format. Why??

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: True

formatters:
    my_std:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        datefmt: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: my_std
        level: DEBUG
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: my_std
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8
    rosconsole:
        class: rosgraph.roslogging.RosStreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: my_std
        colorize: True

loggers:
    my_module:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: no
    rosout:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [rosconsole]
        propagate: yes
        qualname: rosout

root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, rosconsole]
```

Comment: You can use `rospy.loginfo()` in ros-python and `ROS_INFO()` in ros-C++ and integrate them in a scene, but I don't know about other loggers in various language that will integrated together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config yaml does the trick:

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: True

formatters:
    my_std:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        datefmt: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: my_std
        level: DEBUG
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: my_std
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
    __main__:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: no
    rosout:
        level: INFO
        propagate: yes
        qualname: rosout

root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler]
```

And to load it,

```
import logging
import yaml

if os.path.exists(config_path):
    with open(config_path, 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rospy.loginfo()` that made for ROS-Python and `ROS_INFO()` that made of ROS-C++ and integrate them in a scene. For that do as following:

```
$ roscd log
```

You will see several `.log` files, then use the following command to track them.

```
$ tail -f <logfile-name.log>
```

[**UPDATE**]
Also, you could subscribe to `/rosout` topic or echo this topic (`$ rostopic echo /rosout`).
[Reference](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging).

---

Answer (score 0):

In python, I use the standard logger library and remap the logger to ROS_LOG.  Note that ROS_LOG won't respect formatting if you try to use ros_stream_handler.setFormatter.

```
import logging
from rosgraph.roslogging import RosStreamHandler as RosStreamHandler

ros_stream_handler = RosStreamHandler()
ros_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ros_stream_handler)
```